# Save File to a desired location with a defined file naming convention

Tags: c#

I want to save opened picture to a predefined location with a defined naming convention such as date+ original name. How can a eliminate to be asked the file name and folder by savedialog;

```
Image Dosya;
private void btnopen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog of = new OpenFileDialog();
            of.Filter = "Jpg|*.Jpg";
            if (of.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
            {

                Dosya = Image.FromFile(of.FileName);
                pictureBox1.Image = Dosya;
            }
        }

 private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        SaveFileDialog sd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sd.InitialDirectory = "C:\\Users\\sonyy\\Videos\\";
        sd.Title = "Save Files";
        sd.CheckFileExists = true;
        sd.CheckPathExists = true;
        sd.DefaultExt = "jpg";
        sd.Filter = "JPG(*.jpg)|*.jpg|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        sd.FilterIndex = 1;
        sd.RestoreDirectory = false;

        if (sd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string dosyaadi = sd.InitialDirectory;
            string date = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString());
            sd.FileName = date;
            Dosya.Save(sd.InitialDirectory+date+"."+sd.DefaultExt);
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to ask the user to select a folder, not a file? Are you using WinForms? Use [FolderBrowserDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: nop I am trying to save the selected picture to a predefined tolder.

Comment: Then I think you want [OpenFileDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx). Your question is very hard to understand.

Comment: Yes I think It was not clear enough. I want to save the picture which I have opened. to a predefined folder. II don't want to choose folder from dialog. And name should be given automaticaly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to open the file save dialog.
You know what's the path, you know what's the name (date time for example).
Simply save the file without showing the dialog.
Use the [Image.Save](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktx83wah(v=vs.110).aspx) assuming you have the image.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
Image Dosya;
private void btnopen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog of = new OpenFileDialog();
            of.Filter = "Jpg|*.Jpg";
            if (of.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
            {

                Dosya = Image.FromFile(of.FileName);
                pictureBox1.Image = Dosya;
            }
        }

 private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        SaveFileDialog sd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sd.InitialDirectory = "C:\\Users\\sonyy\\Videos\\";
        sd.Title = "Save Files";
        sd.CheckFileExists = true;
        sd.CheckPathExists = true;
        sd.DefaultExt = "jpg";
        sd.Filter = "JPG(*.jpg)|*.jpg|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        sd.FilterIndex = 1;
        sd.RestoreDirectory = false;

            string dosyaadi = sd.InitialDirectory;
            string date = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString());
            sd.FileName = date;
            Dosya.Save(sd.InitialDirectory+date+"."+sd.DefaultExt);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 SaveFileDialog sd = new SaveFileDialog();

            sd.InitialDirectory = "C:\\Users\\sonyy\\Videos\\";

            sd.Title = "Save Files";

            //sd.CheckFileExists = true;

            sd.CheckPathExists = true;

            sd.DefaultExt = "jpg";

            sd.Filter = "JPG(*.jpg)|*.jpg|All files (*.*)|*.*";

            sd.FilterIndex = 1;

            sd.RestoreDirectory = false;



            if (sd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string dosyaadi = sd.InitialDirectory;
                string date = Convert.ToString(DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString());
                sd.FileName = date;
                Dosya.Save(date + "." + sd.DefaultExt);

            }
```